# d3 v4 vertical bar chart issue with text on the bars

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js, bar-chart

I am trying to add the simple text on top of the bars, tried adding the same x and y coordinates used for bars to add the text but for some it doesn't work, i know it is simple but unable to catch it, could someone please the point the mistake?, any help is much appreciated. [StackBlitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rs33lv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple *d3 selection enter/update* issue. If you look at the console, you get a better picture of why were you not able to view the texts. That's because the texts were being appended to the `rect`s

Changing the *d3 enter selection* code to:

```
const bar = svg
  .selectAll('.bar')
  .data(chartData)
  .enter().append('g').attr('class', 'bar');

bar
  .append('rect')
  .attr('x', d => this._xScale(d.name))
  ....

bar
  .append('text')
  .attr('class', 'barText')
  ...
```

Now if you check the console, you see that the `text`s are a part of a group `<g>` (classed **bar**) with `rect` and `text` as separate elements. This is how you append text within a rect.

Fork: [StackBlitz bar chart fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhe6md?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Hope this helps.

Comment: got it, thank you very much for your time and another set of fresh eyes always helps!

Comment: Glad I could help.